# Program to reverse a string in c, but its printing a at the /0 position

Tags: c

The program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    int l,i;
    char s[10],c;
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    gets(s);
    l=strlen(s);

    for(i=0;i<l/2;i++){
        c=s[i];
        s[i]=s[l-1-i];
        s[l-1-i]=c;
    }
    printf("The reversed string is: %s ",s);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

The output is:
Enter the string: hello world.
The reversed string is: hlrow olleo.

Comment: The string "hello world" doesn't fit into an array of 10 characters.

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as mentioned by @Passerby, the gets function should no longer be used. Instead, you can use the fgets() function to take the input.

```
fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);  // read string
```

Secondly, you are storing your input in an array of size 10, whereas your input string is of length 11. So, the 'd' of 'world' is not read at all. Change the array size to a bigger value and replace gets with fgets, and the problem will be fixed.

```
char s[15], c;
```

Comment: Worth a mention after `fgets()`, `s[strcspn (s, "\n")] = 0;` will trim the `'\n'` from the end of the input by overwriting with the *nul-character*. Also worth reminding of the cardinal rule **"Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!!"**. `char s[1024];` is fine on PCs, for embedded systems, not less than `char s[32];`...

Answer (score 0):

just try to increase the size of array of character bcoz the size of input string "hello world" is greater than 10 OR try to insert small string like "hi world"